# php ssh echo $! is not show real pid

Tags: php, linux, bash, ssh

After many attempts we failed to do was get the pid number.

code:

```
    <?php

    $server = "optimus.xxx.xx";
    //ip address will work too i.e. 192.168.254.254 just make sure this is your public ip address not private as is the example

    //specify your username
    $username = "root";

    //select port to use for SSH
    $port = "22";

    //command that will be run on server B
    $command = "./sp-sc-auth sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/149255 3908 8908 > /dev/null &";
    //$command = "./sop.sh sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/149255 1234 > /dev/null & echo $!";
    //$command = "./sop.sh sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/149255 1234 & echo $!"; // scoate si restu de info
    //$command = "ps - ef | grep -v grep | grep ./sop.sh sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/149255 1234 | awk '{print $2}'";

    //form full command with ssh and command, you will need to use links above for auto authentication help
    $cmd_string = "ssh -p ".$port." ".$username."@".$server." ".$command;


    //this will run the above command on server A (localhost of the php file)
    exec($cmd_string, $output);
    //return the output to the browser
    //This will output the uptime for server B on page on server A

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($output);
    echo '</pre>';

?>
```

if exchange from this :

```
$command = "./sp-sc-auth sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/149255 3908 8908 > /dev/null & echo $!";
```

is show another number not real number pid.

and if put this from bash is work fine and show the pid.
I do not understand where wrong.

from php is show this pid:

```
Array
```

(
    [0] => 9397
)

and real pid is 7452

Edit:
Desktop  acces web server (server 1) and server 1 start inside server 2 sopcast player. and server 2 is send pid a server 1 for show in web server json.

[image]

Edit 2:

pid number which is the number of ppid him out from the web server, not the server 2 where it runs command sent via ssh.

Comment: Are you properly escaping $ so PHP doesn't think it's a variable?  `echo \$!`

Comment: What is the difference between the "real" process id and the "not real" process id? What does "real" _really_ mean here? Keep in mind that an ssh connection definitely creates another shell environment, so another process. Same with php's `exec` command.

Comment: Brandon  add this \ is not change id pid  is not work

Comment: @arkascha  if not put this " > /dev/null" is show an infinite text

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you try to say with your last comment...

Comment: you refer to put it?  ./sp-sc-auth sop://broker.sopcast.com:3912/149255 3908 8908 & echo $!

Comment: i am edit , and add more info

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, it is not obvious which pid you want. So here is how I have figured it out before:

From pids.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Current pid: $$"
echo "Current process: $(ps -f $$)"

ppid=$(ps -o ppid= -p $$)
echo "Parent pid: $ppid"
echo "Paren process: $(ps -f $ppid)"

gppid=$(ps -o ppid= -p $ppid)
echo "Grand Parent pid: $gppid"
echo "Grand Paren process: $(ps -f $gppid)"
```

## ./pids.sh

```
Current pid: 611
Current process: UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
root       611 31197  0 06:41 pts/1    S+     0:00 /bin/bash ./pids.sh
Parent pid: 31197
Paren process: UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
root     31197 31195  0 04:55 pts/1    Ss     0:00 -bash
Grand Parent pid: 31195
Grand Paren process: UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY      STAT   TIME CMD
root     31195  1216  0 04:55 ?        Ss     0:00 sshd: root@pts/1
```

Also, the linux command pstree can help.

Comment: does not help.
Application 1, accesses the web server (server 1) that connects remote, server 2 and starts sopcast player. But in php from server 1 appears the pid from server 2